# How can I suppress the date when using pandoc to convert md to pdf?

Tags: pandoc

I would like to create a simple pdf file from a markdown file with a title and author but no date. I cannot figure out how to suppress the date without having to edit an intermediate tex file.

```
---
title: Test Doc
author: My Name
---

# Some Heading Here

Text here.
```

When you try the command `pandoc test.md -o test.pdf`
The date always appears in the pdf. I have tried setting the `date:` yaml block to all sorts of spaces, blanks, and other combinations, but cannot figure out how to get it to be blank.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandoc uses [templates](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates). To generate PDFs, by default it uses a LaTeX template, which you can print with `pandoc -D latex`. In an older pandoc version, this template contained:

```
$if(date)$
\date{$date$}
$endif$
```

which causes your issue because for some reason, LaTeX prints the date if you leave the `\date{}` command out. So either upgrade your pandoc version or modify your template manually to contain just

```
\date{$date$}
```

or use ConTeXt instead of LaTeX:

```
pandoc -s -t context test.md -o test.tex && context test.tex
```